# Copying and add a range of rows into another range of rows in same sheet (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

Somewhat a newbie into Excel VBA.
How do I copy a range of rows (perhaps chosen by an Inputbox) and add these rows into another range of rows (Inputbox?)?

Example: Before

```
121, tileX, data    
122, tileX, data    
123, tileX, data    
223, tileY, data    
323, tileZ, data    
423, tileW, data
```

After:

```
121, tileX, data    
122, tileX, data    
123, tileX, data    
223, tileY, data    
121, tileX, data    
122, tileX, data    
123, tileX, data    
323, tileZ, data    
121, tileX, data    
122, tileX, data    
123, tileX, data    
423, tileW, data    
121, tileX, data    
122, tileX, data    
123, tileX, data
```

Comment: Do you mean you'd like a textbox where you can input a range e.g A1:C6 and then a button which copies the values in that range to another location?

Comment: That question was a bit cryptic to me.

Comment: I mean that I want to copy a range of rows, e.g. 1:6 into a second range of rows that repeat the first range of rows for each second row until the second range of rows has copies of the first range of rows inserted.